# Android app crashes when button placed in fragment is clicked

Tags: android, button, android-fragments, onclick

In my current Android project, I have a Fragment which layout (`headlines_view.xml`) have multiple buttons like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/button_icon"
    android:text="@string/button1"
    android:onClick="openTab1" />
```

the implementation for the method `openTab1` is placed in a class `HeadlinesFragment` derived from Fragment, and looks like that:

```
/** Called when the user touches the button */
public void openTab1(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button click
    Tab1Fragment newFragment = new Tab1Fragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
    // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    // Commit the transaction
    transaction.commit();
}
```

when I run the app and touch the button, the application crashes. what I am doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

full code for headlinesFragment:

```
public class HeadlinesFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.headlines_view, container, false);
    }

    /** Called when the user touches the button */
    public void openTab1(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button click
        Tab1Fragment newFragment = new Tab1Fragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
    }

    /** Called when the user touches the button */
    public void openTab2(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button click
        Tab2Fragment newFragment = new Tab2Fragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
    }

    /** Called when the user touches the button */
    public void openTab3(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button click
        Tab3Fragment newFragment = new Tab3Fragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
    }

    /** Called when the user touches the button */
    public void openTab4(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button click
        Tab4Fragment newFragment = new Tab4Fragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
    }

    /** Called when the user touches the button */
    public void openTab5(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button click
        Tab5Fragment newFragment = new Tab5Fragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
    }

}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I remove the code for handle the click from Fragment class and put in the activity class. That's the current code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hello_layout);

    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        Tab1Fragment newFragment = new Tab1Fragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
      }
    });
}
```

when I run the app in my phone, I got this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(18494): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(18494): Process: org.hello, PID: 18494
E/AndroidRuntime(18494): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f070000 (org.hello:id/fragment_container) for fragment Tab1Fragment{4214af38 #2 id=0x7f070000}
E/AndroidRuntime(18494):        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:882)
E/AndroidRuntime(18494):        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
E/AndroidRuntime(18494):        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
E/AndroidRuntime(18494):        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
E/AndroidRuntime(18494):        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
E/AndroidRuntime(18494):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
E/AndroidRuntime(18494):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(18494):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime(18494):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
E/AndroidRuntime(18494):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(18494):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(18494):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
E/AndroidRuntime(18494):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
E/AndroidRuntime(18494):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  916):   Force finishing activity org.hello/.HelloActivity
```

layout article_view.xml, where is placed the view with id fragment_container:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: what is the stacktrace?

Comment: please post your complete code and logcat error.

Comment: **Nullpointer** May be??

Comment: use getChildFragmentManager() in place of getFragmentManager()

Comment: @mapo where I can find that one? I run the app in the emulator and in my phone, and can't see any stacktrace in the terminal.

Comment: did you select the right device for showing up in the logcat?

Comment: @blackbelt with this option I can't build the project (error: `[ERROR] /home/kleber/workspace/basic_app/src/main/java/org/hello/HeadlinesFragment.java:[21,42] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getChildFragmentManager()
[ERROR] location: class HeadlinesFragment`

Comment: is HeadlinesFragment a Fragment ?

Comment: @mapo where I can select the device? I am building the project with maven (mvn package and mvn android:deploy).

Comment: @blackbelt yes, it is.

Comment: @blackbelt just add the complete code for this fragment.

Comment: Place the implementation in the `Activity` class instead of the Fragment class

Comment: @JoelFernandes I only have one Activity (it's the launcher). I can add this methods to this activity or I need create one activity for each fragment?

Comment: @KleberMota An activity can have any number of Fragments. A fragment can be associated with only one Activity.

Comment: @mapo stacktrace for the error added to the question (see update 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New Answer based on stack trace given**

The problem is your parent activity layout must have the container as a child. The id passed into Fragment transaction replace must be a child of the layout specified in your activities setContentView

Basically.

Your container which you named as "fragment_container" must be inside the layout of "R.layout.hello_layout" which you set as the content view in onCreate. You will then replace this container with your fragment.

Here is an small example

This is the layout of my main activity. activity_main.xml

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_image_selector_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

This is my main activity

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageSelectorFragment imageSelectorFragment = new ImageSelectorFragment();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.activity_main_image_selector_container,imageSelectorFragment,ImageSelectorFragment.class.getName());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Notice how the activity_main_image_selector_container resides in the main activity layout and is used as the container to replace the fragment with (put the fragment in that container).

Comment: I try this way but still got the app crashed when the button is clicked.

Comment: @KleberMota, could you post the stack trace you get from log cat when the app crashes. The problem could be in one of the tab fragments. the crash report will help pin point where the problem is coming from

Comment: I just add the stacktrace for the error being triggered when I run the app in my phone.

Comment: @Kleber Mota I have updated my answer. Please let me know if you have further questions

Comment: @KleberMota wrote a small example just to clarify things

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared R.id.fragment_container!

Comment: how's that? fragment_container is declared in the layout article_view.xml, right?